# script tag VS Html codes priority

Tags: javascript, html, browser, frontend

in the below codes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <span>1111</span>
    
    <script>
      alert("1");
    </script>
    
    <span>22222</span>
    
    <script>
      alert("2");
    </script>
    
      <span>Hello World</span>
     <script>
       alert("Hello World");
     </script>
      
  </body>
</html>
```

In the body tag there are some span tags that after each one there are one script tag. in the each script tag just an alert there is.

When I open these codes by a browser, I expect that span tags executed(rendered) before than alerts. because spans are before than alerts (alerts are after than spans!)

But In the real test, it is not as I expected (first alerts shown and then spans will appear.)
Why?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that a browser is like a hybrid car, except that while a hybrid car has two different fuel sources, the browser has several different parsing, processing/interpreting and rendering “engines“. This includes the HTML parser, the CSS, rendering engine, the JavaScript runtime, the XML/XSLT, parser, etc., and, of course the native browser’s core programming.

These different “engines“ are all designed to process particular aspects of the code found in a webpage, and these “engines“ each have the ability to process what they are parsing at different speeds and with different synchronicity.

A `<span>` element is HTML and therefore is processed (parsed) by the HTML parser.

`alert()` is a method of the `window` object and not actually JavaScript. In other words `alert()` is an API call into the `window` object.

The `window` object and its various methods are processed and (when appropriate) rendered by the browser's core programming (written in native code) rather than the JavaScript runtime or CSS rendering engine.

The browser's core programming can process and render much faster than JS/CSS code can and therefore, there are times when you call the `window` API, the results are provided faster than the HTML parser & CSS Rendering Engine or the JS runtime can.

In the case of the `alert()`, the native browser engine can (and usually does) process those calls faster than the HTML parser and CSS rendering engine can processes and it produces a modal dialog and blocks the UI from updating, so that manages to process quicker than the `span` elements can render.

### So, can you do anything to affect the normal blocking sequence of the `alert()`?

Yes! If you embed a very short delay before the call for the `alert()`, it will give the CSS rendering engine enough time to render the `span` elements before the `alert()`. Here's an example.

Without the delay:

```html
<span>TEST</span>
<script>
  alert("Hello!");
</script>
```

With the delay:

```html
<span>TEST</span>
<script>
  // setTimeout is another windows API that you can use
  // to cause a delay in processing a function. In this
  // case, we're specifying a 10 millisecond delay. Now,
  // you can't absolutely count on an exact delay of 10
  // milliseconds, but you can count on AT LEAST a 10
  // millisecond delay.
  setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Hello!");
  }, 10);
</script>
```

Comment: Can I say: there is a competition between HTML parser(HTML renderer) and browser's core programming(window APIs executer) ?!

Comment: @Mohammad In a sense, yes. And, don't forget to include any other parser/interpreter that the browser has (JS, CSS, XML, SVG, etc.).

Comment: Excuse me, Can more explain about "the native browser engine can (and usually does) process those calls faster than the JS engine processes" at the last paragraph? actually my question about it is: for show an alert, JS engine do it or native browser engine?, or JS engine call the native browser engine for show dialog?

Comment: @Mohammad the JavaScript engine, will read that line and know that it must be passed over to the native browser to actually carry out because window is a part of the browsers object model.

Comment: I think you should write "HTML parser" instead of "JS engine processe" at the last paragraph of your answer (in the "faster than the JS engine processes ") - Am I wrong?!

Comment: @Mohammad Yes, you are correct. I’ve made several edits, so please read the entire answer again for better clarity. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your perfect answer. I accepted your answer.